# What's the difference between multiclass categorical crossentropy, mlogloss and multi:softprob?

Tags: classification, xgboost, loss-function, multiclass-classification

As far as I understand, an objective is something I'm trying to optimize and an evaluation statistic is something I use to look for overfitting. I stumbled upon 4 losses that seem to be the same, but I'm not quite sure.

1. In XGBoost, one of the objectives for multi class classification is `multi:softprob` (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters). I couldn't find any formulas in the documentation, but apparently this objective returns "predicted probability of each data point belonging to each class", so an "`ndata * nclass` matrix".
2. One of XGBoost's `eval_metric`s is `mlogloss`. The documentation (same link as above) links to [`sklearn.metrics.log_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html), which is "log loss, aka logistic loss or cross-entropy loss". `sklearn`'s [User Guide about log loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#log-loss) provides this formula:
   $$
   L(Y, P) = -\frac1N \sum_i^N \sum_k^K y_{i,k} \log p_{i,k}
   $$
   So apparently, `mlogloss` and (multiclass categorical) cross-entropy loss are the same.
3. The [Otto Group Product Classification Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/overview/evaluation) talks about "the multi-class logarithmic loss" and gives the same formula as above, so looks like `mlogloss`, cross-entropy loss and multi-class logarithmic loss are all the same.

Now, I'm not particularly sure what `multi:softprob` is. `multi:softmax` is [softmax](https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy) - the activation function used in neural networks, for example. However, it's not a measure of error, like cross-entropy loss, right? Why is it one of the objectives in XGBoost, then? Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any useful information about `multi:softprob`, except that it's *not* the same as softmax because softprob outputs a vector of probabilities and softmax - ["a class output"](https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/softmax-vs-softprob-difference/1163) (so the ID of a class, I presume?).

---

Am I correct that `mlogloss`, cross-entropy loss and multi-class logarithmic loss are the same thing? How are they different from `multi:softprob`? What *is* `multi:softprob` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) of XGBoost you can see that multi:softmax and multi:softprob are the same objective. The only difference is that
multi:softprob also return output vector of ndata * nclass of the classes probabilities.

**multi:softmax**: set XGBoost to do multiclass classification using the softmax objective, you also need to set num_class(number of classes)

**multi:softprob**: same as softmax, but output a vector of ndata * nclass, which can be further reshaped to ndata * nclass matrix. The result contains predicted probability of each data point belonging to each class.